# Adding custom view with radio button to radio group

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a custom view that holds, among other views, a RadioButton.

The SingleRadioItem:

```
public class SingleRadioItem extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView mTextKey;
    private RadioButton mRadioButton;
    private ImageView mImageSeparator;

    public SingleRadioItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rtl_single_radio_item, this, true);

        mTextKey = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.single_radio_item_text_key);
        mRadioButton = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.single_radio_item_button);
        mImageSeparator = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.single_image_separator);
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        mTextKey.setText(key);
    }

    public boolean getSelectedState() {
        return mRadioButton.isSelected();
    }

    public void setSelectedState(boolean selected) {
        mRadioButton.setSelected(selected);
    }
}
```

I want to create instances of this view, add them to a RadioGroup and add the RadioGroup to a LinearLayout.
When I do so, it allows me to set all the radio buttons as selected, which means, the RadioGroup isn't functioning well (probably because how I do it..)

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
        radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

        SingleRadioItem radio1 = new SingleRadioItem(this, null);
        SingleRadioItem radio2 = new SingleRadioItem(this, null);

        radioGroup.addView(radio1);
        radioGroup.addView(radio2);

        updateDetailsView.addView(radioGroup);
```

Obviously, when I add `RadioButton radio1 = new RadioButton(this);` the RadioGroup works well.

Is it even possible to add a view that holds a radio button to a radiogroup and I'm just missing something or not possible at all?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**
To extend @cosmincalistru Answer and help others:

for each SingleRadioItem I added to the LinearLayout I attached a listener like this:

```
radio1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (lastRadioChecked != null) {
                    lastRadioChecked.setCheckedState(false);
                }

                lastRadioChecked = (SingleRadioItem)v;
                lastRadioChecked.setCheckedState(true);
            }
        });
```

You also need to set the RadioButton View inside the SingleRadioItem XML to clickable:false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RadioButton has to be directly subordinated to the RadioGroup, otherwise your buttons will be considered as from different groups.
The best idea is to use listeners on each RadioButton in your case.

EDIT:
Whenever i want to make a group of RadioButtons as part from a group but can't use the RadioGroup i do something like this :

```
RadioButton r1,r2,....;
// Instantiate all your buttons;
...
// Set listener on each
for(each RadioButton) {
    rx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                //set all buttons to false;
                for(each RadioButton) {
                    rx.setChecked(false);
                }
                //set new selected button to true;
                buttonView.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a view to RadioGroup, only if the view is a instanceof RadioButton only then will the group work correctly. In your case you are adding a LinearLayout. So SingleRadioItem should extend RadioButton.